# How do I configure the sonar eclipse plugin?

Tags: android, eclipse, sonarqube

I installed the sonar plugin for eclipse using this [guide][1].

I configure my android project with sonar as associate with server **http://localhost:9000**. Then I click on `find on server`(Select projects to add Sonar capability.).

I selected my project and clicked find on server. but when I click on finish its showing an error as

`empty GroupId for project 'Personal Certificates'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1.Check that the `groupId` is actually there in your `main.xml`.

2.Check that the `artifactId` and the eclipse project name are the same.

3.Check that you typed `groupId` and `artifactId` in the associate with sonar dialog window.
Then click find on server.

4.Also make sure that the sonar plugin is set up on your eclipse (by going to Windows->Preferences->Sonar).